# Apache rewrite rule to Nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I'm looking to rewrite htaccess rules into nginx rules

Here is my htaccess that need to be converted:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?c/([^/]+)/?$ search_result.php?category_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^d/([^/.]+)/?$    detail.php    [NC,L]
```

I tried [this site](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess), then insert into my vhost domain.conf:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/?c/([^/]+)/?$ /search_result.php?category_id=$1 break;
}

location /d {
    rewrite ^/d/([^/.]+)/?$ /detail.php break;
}
```

But for some reason when i browse the detail page (that is rewritten) , nginx serve the source code php file instead of executing it ..

here is my original location section

```
    # Main Settings
location / {
    root   /home/sites/mysite.com;
    index  index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
        gzip_vary on; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does your `location ~ \.php$ {...` block look like?

Comment: i have edited the post Darren thank you

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting a URI to a `.php` requires the use of `last` rather than `break` as the `.php` is processed within a different `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

You could place the rules within the existing `location /` block or outside of it. Do not create a new `location /` block, as that would cause an error.

Use `nginx -T` to test your configuration.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/c/([^/]+)/?$ /search_result.php?category_id=$1 last;
rewrite ^/d/([^/.]+)/?$ /detail.php last;

location / {
    root   /home/sites/mysite.com;
    index  index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks you Richard, i have fixed the problem with your directive , i have also voted but i do not have enough point for this , all the best to you guys